# POST action returns the model in a valid state but returns Model.Count as 0 when using foreach or for loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, tag-helpers

As shown in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39542717/1232087) the GET action method `Test(..)` works fine when using `foreach` loop in the corresponding `Test.chtml` view but the POST action method `Test(...)` returns null. But, as mentioned by many users, the `foreach` is not reliable for POST method. So, I decided to use the `for` loop as shown below. But that returned unexpected results in the view since, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39542717/1232087), in a `foreach`loop type casting is done automatically but in `for` loop you have to type cast the objects `Model[i].BlogID` etc to a proper class object type.

So, I decided to type cast the objects `Model[i].BlogID` etc to a `BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel` class object type as shown in the second version of Test.cshml view below; and this time the `Test.cshtml` view is displayng the correct records. But although the `submit` button in the view is sending a a valid model (`ModelState.IsValid` is true) the `Model.Count` is 0 that results in no update to database. Why `Model.Count` is 0 and how to correct it? As you can see below the html page source of the view is showing the name attributes of the tags matching the property values in the View Model.

**Note**: For complete code, please [see this OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39542717/1232087). I'm using ASP.NET Core with EF Core and [Tag Helpers](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro.html).

**Test.cshtml view with `for` loop - without type casting the loop objects**:

```
@model IList<ASP_Core_Blogs.Models.BlogPostViewModels.BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel>
@using ASP_Core_Blogs.Models.BlogPostViewModels 
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-controller="Blogs" asp-action="Test" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post">
            @{
                IEnumerable<SelectListItem> yearsList = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.YearsList;
                var currentlySelectedIndex = 0; // Currently selected index (usually will come from model)
            }
            <strong>Select a Post Year</strong>
            <h6>Choose a year and a URL to begin:</h6>
            <label>Year:</label><select asp-for="@currentlySelectedIndex" asp-items="yearsList"></select><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="GO" value="GO" />
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Url</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Content</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i=0; i< Model.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].BlogID" /></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i]).PostID" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" asp-for="@Model[i].Url" style="border:0;" readonly />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input asp-for="@Model[i].Title" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input asp-for="@Model[i].Content" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Test.cshtml view with for loop objects being casted as BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel class objects:**

```
@model IList<ASP_Core_Blogs.Models.BlogPostViewModels.BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel>
@using ASP_Core_Blogs.Models.BlogPostViewModels 
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-controller="Blogs" asp-action="Test" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post">
            @{
                IEnumerable<SelectListItem> yearsList = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.YearsList;
                var currentlySelectedIndex = 0; // Currently selected index (usually will come from model)
            }
            <strong>Select a Post Year</strong>
            <h6>Choose a year and a URL to begin:</h6>
            <label>Year:</label><select asp-for="@currentlySelectedIndex" asp-items="yearsList"></select><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="GO" value="GO" />
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Url</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Content</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i=0; i< Model.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="hidden" asp-for="((BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel)@Model[i]).BlogID" /></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" asp-for="((BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel)@Model[i]).PostID" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" asp-for="((BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel)@Model[i]).Url" style="border:0;" readonly />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input asp-for="((BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel)@Model[i]).Title" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input asp-for="((BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel)@Model[i]).Content" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**A Portion of html generated by View after Submit**:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The BlogID field is required." id="BlogID" name="BlogID" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PostID field is required." id="PostID" name="PostID" value="1" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" style="border:0;" readonly id="Url" name="Url" value="blog1@test.com" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" value="Title1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="Content" name="Content" value="Content1" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You do not (and should not) have to cast it - your view already declares the model as `@model List<BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel>` (and your generating `name="BlogID"` instead of `name="[0].BlogID"` which is required for binding to a collection as explained in the dupe to your linked question). What _unexpected results_ were you getting?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've created a separate post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39554736/1232087) for unexpected results giving example and more details.